# Encryption using ecryptfs

Tags: kubuntu, encryption, ecryptfs

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.  I installed ecryptfs but Private folder is not encrypted.  I ran...
sudo apt-get install ecryptfs-utils
Then I ran...
ecryptfs-setup-private
The terminal output looked like this...
[image]

I have a .ecryptfs, .Private, and Private folder in /Home.  Problem seems to be files don't appear to be encryptd when I save in either.

Comment: After logging out & back in, it still wasn't working? How do you know it's not working? Tried `ecryptfs-mount-private` & `ecryptfs-umount-private`?

Comment: I believe it's not working because I see any files I put in the Private folder. I run... sudo ecryptfs-mount-private
Enter your login passphrase:
Inserted auth tok with sig [1c0e4b08f20b7jf2] into the user session keyring
fopen: No such file or directory

Comment: Kleopatra shows I am certified Open PGP with a key ID.  I click "Signn/Encrypt" and it prompts for passphrased, I enter it but nothing seems to change in my Private folder.

Comment: You shouldn't need sudo, it might even cause problems. If there's an error message do paste it into the question (it preserves formatting better than a comment).  When logged in does `mount` show anything in your home (`mount | grep "$HOME"`)? And what's the contents of the `~/.ecryptfs/` folder, and `.Private` & `Private` when logged in *and not logged in* (check with another user account). pgp/gpg's unrelated to ecryptfs, kleopatra might show some keyrings & keys but I'm not too sure about that, it shouldn't directly affect ecryptfs either (as long as you don't delete any keys with it ;-)

Comment: mark@mark-TP300LDB:~$ mount | grep "$HOME"
/home/mark/.Private on /home/mark/Private type ecryptfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=f9d638b698g3600e,ecryptfs_sig=1c0e2b08f40b72f9,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs)

Comment: mark@mark-TP300LDB:~/.ecryptfs ls
auto-mount  auto-umount  Private.mnt  Private.sig  wrapped-passphrase

Comment: I am trying to encrypt a file on EXT4 USB 1Tb drive so it will not be readable from  Windows10.

Comment: I think I can read that ecryptfs was mounted to your `~/Private` folder (please do edit new info like that into your question, that kind of stuff has no formatting in comments). So creating some files in `~/Private/` should actually create encrypted files in `~/.Private/`, and when you log out the new files should not be visible in `~/Private/` (unless you've got the "ecryptfs doesn't unmount" bug). So what happens?

Comment: I see encrypted files in ~/.Private ( in dev/sda9/home/mark/.Private) but I want the encrypted files in /dev/sdb1/foldername. I can open the encrypted files with Kleopatra.   I also see the readable file in ~/Private.

Comment: I was able to direct the kleopatra (ecryptfs GUI?) output to /dev/sdb1/foldername. I then deleted the files in ~/Private since I didn't need them.  Now kleopatra crashes upon opening.  Is the a log file so I can see why kleopatra is crashing?

Comment: I don't know about kleopatra, and I've read that moving an ecryptfs folder is a little involved... but those are both separate questions. So does this mean your Private/.Private ecryptfs encryption is working now? Was it always working, or did the main problem of this Q go away on it's own?

Comment: I was getting encrypted files using kleopatra but since it crashed, not working.  I'll have to try from the terminal once I figure out the syntax.

Comment: From the earlier mount line, ecryptfs should have been working. Just testing it by writing new files to `~/Private` (no dot) then logging out & logging in as another user (or booting a live USB/DVD) and verifying the new files aren't readable in that Private folder should verify it's working.

Comment: This is what I don't get...If I copy a file to ~/Private, then login as another user, I won't see what's in ~/Private anyway since I won't have access to that directory as the user that created it.

Comment: The permissions might give read permission to all, or you can use sudo to view the files no matter what. I suspect it's been working all along

Comment: I would like to encrypt a folder on a USB drive.  Should I just create a symbolic link to the USB folder in ~/Private?

Comment: Have to focus on this question first, if ecryptfs is actually working OK then maybe this Q should be deleted, then you can ask a new one about folders on USB's (consider LUKS for a whole USB)

Comment: I believe it is working.  I cannot open the ~/Private folder from a different account.  My confusion was with the use of Kleopatra.  I was creating GPG files in ~/Private and was trying to decrypt files in ~/Private.  Now I have 4 ~/Private/.directory files and 4 other files all with the same name (don't know how that's possible) .  Can I just delete these without issue?